# Git and I mucked up and renamed my branch to staging BUT its still referencing merged branch

Tags: git

So, I was having issues with my staging branch. I believe someone deleted some files from it and when I tried to merge my branch into it, the "deleted files" would never update. Its like my branch was behind the staging and thus it wouldn't update (or put back) those deleted files.

Since my branch was the "latest" I thought to just rename my branch to "staging" and solve it...... well, it is now staging, but its tracking the older branch!!

HOW DO I just have staging be staging... and have my old branch back.

This is what it is showing me:

```
➜  My_Site git:(staging) git status
On branch staging
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/issue-118/customer-page'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

So, I am on "staging" now, but its referencing the "old" branch. I used these commands. I think I mucked up. I Just wanted "staging" to be forced or overwritten completely with my branch..... but I renamed things... and made a mess. This is what I did. I see that it was incorrect.

````
```
git branch -m staging old_staging
git branch -m issue-118/customer-page staging
git push -f origin staging
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> well, it is now staging, but its tracking the older branch!

The word *track* in Git is badly overloaded: it is indeed "tracking" the wrong remote-tracking name, and you'll find various pieces of Git use that verb, but other pieces of Git use the word *upstream* or *set-upstream*.  That's a better name because it's far less overloaded (can be distinguished easily from tracked vs untracked files, for instance).

Using the "upstream" and "set an upstream" wording, you'll find `git branch --set-upstream-to`.  That's the command you are looking for here.  If you like the fact that the name `staging` currently means whatever commit it currently means, and you'd like the upstream of the renamed-to-`staging` name be `origin/staging`, you just need to add one more command to the set you have already run:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/staging staging
```

This tells Git to set the upstream of `staging` to be `origin/staging`, instead of `origin/issue-118/customer-page`.

You could also have used `git push -f -u origin staging` at your `git push` step.

#### Technical details (optional)

*Branch names* within a Git repository are specific to *that* Git repository (that particular clone).  Some other Git repository may be using the same names, and your GitHub or Bitbucket or GitLab or whatever repository, the one you reach with the name `origin`, *is* using the same names.  But their names may refer to different specific commits.  (A branch name always *means* one specific commit; that one commit "reaches" its parent commit(s), which then "reach" their parents, and so on.)

When you use `git fetch` to obtain new commits from some other Git repository, such as the one at `origin`, your own Git grabs those new commits (if any) and then reads their *branch* names, like `staging` and `main` and whatever, and *changes those names* to become your *remote-tracking names:* `origin/staging`, `origin/main`, and so on.  Your Git software then creates or updates these remote-tracking names, so that your Git repository will remember which commits *their* Git repository remembers (but their Git repository is using the variants without `origin/` in front).

Each branch name in your repository *can* have one (but only one) *upstream* set.  There's no *requirement* that any branch have any upstream at all.  Having one is just a convenience feature.

When you use some existing remote-tracking name, such as `origin/develop`, to create a *new* branch in your own repository, using the `--guess` mode that `git checkout` and `git switch` offer (and it's on by default), your Git software will create that branch *and* immediately set its upstream to the corresponding remote-tracking name.  So if you use `git switch develop` when you don't yet *have* a `develop`, and your Git sees that you *do* have `origin/develop`, your Git will guess that you meant to make a new `develop` that has `origin/develop` as its upstream *and* selects the same commit that `origin/develop` selects right now.  This is the `git switch -c name --track origin/name` or `git checkout -b name --track origin/name` operation in action: the `--track` flag (meaning, set an upstream) is implied by the guess code.<sup>1</sup>

When you create a *new* branch—one that's all new, that has no corresponding branch over on `origin`—such as one for a new feature or bug fix or some such, there isn't any branch with that name in the *other* Git repository yet.  So your local `fix/bug-1234`, for instance, has no `origin/fix/bug-1234` for it to "track" (have as an upstream).

As a result, for a *new* branch like this, you must first `git push` the commit(s) (if any) to `origin`, then—at the end of that `git push`—have the other Git software, working on the `origin` repository, *create* the branch name *there*.  If and when that succeeds, your own Git software will automatically create your `origin/fix/bug-1234`, and *now* you can set an upstream.  So that takes two steps: `git push origin fix/bug-1234` followed by an appropriate `git branch --set-upstream-to`.

To avoid having to run two commands,<sup>3</sup> `git push` has the `-u` flag (with longer spelling `--set-upstream`).  This flag tells `git push` that *if the push succeeds*, thereby creating or updating the remote-tracking name, `git push` should run the `git branch --set-upstream-to` for you.

---

<sup>1</sup>The reason it's `--track` in `git checkout` and `git switch`, but `--set-upstream-to` in `git branch`, is that the core Git team like to confuse everyone.  More seriously, it's because `--track` is for a *new* branch and `--set-upstream-to` is for an *existing* branch.  Also, "set as upstream" is tough to verb well.<sup>2</sup>

Meanwhile, the reason it's `--set-upstream-to` in `git branch`, but just `--set-upstream` elsehwhere, is due to a historical mistake: the initial attempt to add `--set-upstream` to `git branch` produced an unfortunate result.  The `--set-upstream` option to `git branch` now tells you to use `--set-upstream-to` instead.

<sup>2</sup>[As Calvin said, "Verbing weirds language."](https://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/1993/01/25)  What would you put here? `--upstreamify`?

<sup>3</sup>Having to type in *two* commands would be such an awful burden, wouldn't it?  But the `-u` option *is* convenient.  You can do it on every `git push`, or just with the ones that actually need to set or change the upstream: redundantly resetting the upstream is harmless.

---

#### Additional notes

To see how a branch name *means* one particular commit, run `git rev-parse`:

```
git rev-parse staging
git rev-parse old_staging
```

Each command will spit out one hash ID.

This applies to remote-tracking names as well:

```
git rev-parse origin/issue-118/customer-page
```

You can also find out the upstream setting of some branch using `git rev-parse`:

```
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name main
```

which will print `refs/heads/main` if you have a branch named `main` (use `master` if you have `master` instead, and so on); and:

```
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name main@{upstream}
```

will show the full name (including the `refs/remotes/` prefix) of the remote-tracking name that `main` has set as its upstream.  The `@{upstream}` suffix can be shortened to `@{u}`, and in place of a branch name, you can use `HEAD` to mean "the current branch name, whatever it is", so:

```
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD@{u}
```

will tell you what the upstream is of the current branch, if there is an upstream for the current branch.  If not, you'll get an error like this one:

```
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'main'
```

Configuring an upstream gives you some shortcuts, and extra information, and that's most of what it does.  Note that, depending on your `push.default` setting, it might include a *very important* shortcut: the default `push.default` setting, if you have not set it, is `simple`.<sup>4</sup>  This setting *requires* that you use `git push -u origin HEAD` or `git push -u origin branch` for the initial push so that you can just run `git push` with no arguments later.  (If you set `push.default` to `current` or `matching`, this protection goes away, but it's very easy to slip up with these.)

---

<sup>4</sup>If you are using a pre-2.0 Git, this may not be the case.  The old default default was `matching`.  With this setting, a lot of people had a bad time.  The best thing to do here is to upgrade.